# video being ignored in form post

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, laravel, video

I have a form that lets users add videos:

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="video/save" role="form">

// other inputs ...

<input class="form-control" type="file" name="video" accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*" capture="camcorder">
</form>
```

Backend:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    dd($request->input());
}
```

The video is not being sent at all when testing on Android chrome ( Nexus 6 ), works as intended on desktop.

Whats weird is it worked a couple of times in the earlier stages, but is now consistently ignoring "video" , all other data comes through fine.

The page is being served over SSL

**Note:** It seems to work once in a while. Tested on iOS and works flawlessly. I also came across this board ( not sure if its still relevant ), https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2519

**Update:** 
I have since updated the code.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        // other validation rules,
        'video' => 'required|max:20000'
        ]);

    // do stuff
}
```

The validation fails 99% of the time.

As a hack I've changed the form and am using MediaRecorder API in JS to record and upload video blobs in Android, its dirty and I wish I could use the native camcorder. Whats weird is sometimes it works, like once in 50 tries.

Comment: If you change accept to * - does that work? It could be a mimetype issue?

Comment: @Chris No that didnt work - I removed the "accept" attr from the input and that does not work either

Comment: In your controller, try `dd($request->file('video'));`, what is the output?

Comment: @tommy Im only tracking input so it does'nt show the file which is expected.

Comment: I thought that Laravel distinguishes between "input" and "files". So `$request->input()` won't show any files but `$request->file('video')` would.

Comment: @tommy thats correct - but in the updated code it fails validation